# Updating .codeclimate.yml to use Python 3 as well as other languages

Tags: yaml, code-climate

I currently have a `.codeclimate.yml` which starts as follows:

```
---
engines:
  duplication:
    enabled: true
    config:
      languages:
      - ruby
      - javascript
      - python
      - php
```

That is, CodeClimate is configured to work for several languages including Python. I'm running into the issue, however, described at https://github.com/codeclimate/codeclimate-duplication/issues/129, that CodeClimate thinks the code is in Python 2 and raises `SyntaxError`s on Python's newer features like f-strings. Following the instructions at that link, I'd like to update the `.codeclimate.yml` as follows:

```
engines:
  duplication:
    enabled: true
    config:
      languages:
        ruby:
        javascript:
        python:
          python_version: 3
        php:
```

So instead of a sequence of languages, it would become a mapping in which only the `python` key has a sub-mapping with the `python_version`.

I was unable to confirm from the documentation, however, whether this is the right way to update the `.codeclimate.yml`. Would this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example on https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/duplication#section-configure-the-engine, it does indeed seem possible to write the `languages` key in this way, and running the CodeClimate CLI command `codeclimate validate-config` indicates that it is valid.